# Design Pattern for Form Validations

Tags: java, forms, validation, design-patterns

Is there a design pattern which I can follow in JAVA for field validations of my form?

My forms contain some mandatory and non-mandatory fields. Each mandatory field has some sort of validation attached to it. Some non-mandatory fields also have field validations. So when non-mandatory fields are entered, a validation rule for that field will run and accordingly form submission will happen.

Is there any design pattern which allows adding field validations on forms?

(P.S: If field validations are dependent and too many, then if - else branching is too cumbersome)

Comment: [Check out JSR 303 on Bean Validation.](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/)

Comment: Maybe the visitor pattern...

Comment: To add to [Sotirios](http://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis)' comment, please take a look at [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html).  It is an implementation of the JSR 349, which is the next version of the JSR 303.